# Python 4th order diff. Eqn using bvp solver

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python.

Currently I am trying to solve the 4th order diff eqn `d4y/dx4=1`, using python with two boundary conditions `y(0)=y(L)=0`. I am using the bvp solver for the same but am facing errors. The code has been attached below:

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import odeint

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(y,x)  :

  return np.vstack(y[1],y[2],y[3],1)

def bc(ya,yb) :  

   return np.array(ya[0],ya[1],yb[0],yb[1])

xmesh= np.linspace(0,10,1000) 

y= np.zeros((2,xmesh.size))

sol=solve_bvp(fun,bc,xmesh,y)
```

Comment: *"... but am facing errors."*  Whenever you have a question about Python code that generates error, include the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is `fun(x, y)`, the arguments are the other way around. Also the **1** needs to be a vector of suitable size.
2. Lacking some parenthesis in the `array` for `bc`.
3. Your initial guess `y` needs to be of size `(4, len(xmesh))`

Whole things looks like this then:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(x, y):
    return np.vstack([y[1], y[2], y[3], np.ones(y.shape[1])])

def bc(ya, yb) :
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1], yb[0], yb[1]])

xmesh = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.zeros((4, len(xmesh)))
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, xmesh, y)

plt.figure()
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(xmesh, sol.sol(xmesh)[i], label = str(i+1))
plt.legend()
```

Comment: This code worked with np.ones(y.shape[1]) because the rhs of my differential eqn. was 1. Had it been 10, what should have been done? I tried by defining an array consisting of only one element that was 10 and replaced the np.ones with the array name. But the code did not work out.

Comment: The right hand-side of your BVP is a function that is constant to 1. `np.ones(y.shape[1])` represents a discrete function, represented by vector, that is equal to 1. Hope that helps.